# What is the Appropriate Test to Compare Pearson's Correlation Coefficient?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, pearson-r, z-test

Let say I have this simplified data set which contains four variables (2 categorical, and 2 numerical types):

```
    Type  ID  test_A  test_B  
  normal  P1      0.5     50
  normal  P2      0.4     40
  normal  P3      0.2     20
   tumor  P1      0.3     2
   tumor  P2      0.2     3
   tumor  P3      0.1     4
```

Part of the analysis, I ran Person's Correlation test to calculate the correlation coefficient of `test_A` and `test_B` for the two categories `normal` and `tumor`.  The result looks like the following:

```
   Type  Corr_btw_testA_testB
 normal  0.9999999999999992
  tumor  -0.9999999999999997
```

My question is, what is the appropriate statistical test to compare the correlation coefficients and find the significant ones?

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519006/significance-test-on-the-difference-of-two-correlation-coefficient

Comment: Why are you interested in whether the tests correlate and why are you calculating separately for the two disease states? It seems that you have two disease states and two indicators of disease state. I would imagine you want to know which indicator has better sensitivity and specificity for identifying the disease state. If so, you can calculate the AUC and 95% CI for both and compare. You should prespecify what difference is significant before embarking.

Comment: A first comment here is that your correlations are, or should be, **exactly**    1 and -1. Both are described perfectly by straight lines. For your normal your results are testB = 100 test_A and your tumor values testB = 5 - 10 test_A. Code reporting otherwise is a numerical precision problem. That makes the examples so perfect (in one sense) that it's unclear how or indeed whether they have any bearing on your question.

Comment: @Todd I might over simplified the example consequently important details are missing.  The two tests are different in nature.  To add more context, `test_A` is a measure of DNA methylation and `test_B` is the corresponding  gene expression values.  I thought of using Pearson's correlation between the methylation values (i.e. `test_A`) and the expression measurement (i.e. `test_B`), based on the assumption that methylation is associated with expression.  My objective is to know the methylation probes that indicate different correlation with expression in `Normal` versus `Tumor`.

Comment: @Todd I wonder what would be an appropriate way to approach this question ...